# I'm trying to test a function that takes another function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, tdd, enzyme, chai

I am using chai to try and unit test a validation function I have found online. This validation function is being used inside of a 'react-final-form' component.

Here is where I got this validator function from:

https://youtu.be/OEg8jm-NbQ0?t=567

```
import chai, { expect } from "chai";
import chaiEnzyme from "chai-enzyme";

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());

const required = (value) => value === '' ? 'This is required.' : undefined;
const url = (value) => value && !(/^\/[a-z0-9]+$|[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi).test(value) ? 'This does not appear to be a link.': undefined;

const composeValidators = (...validators) => 
  (value) => 
    validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined);

let value = '';

describe("Forms", () => {
  describe("Final form", () => {
    describe("Utils", () => {
      it("Returns correct error message when form field value is empty and field is required", () => {
        expect(composeValidators(required)).to.equal('This is required.');
      });

      it("Returns correct error message when form field value is not empty and field should be a url", () => {
        value = 'not empty';
        expect(composeValidators(url)).to.equal('This does not appear to be a link.');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Currently both assertions are returning [function] instead of the string value I am expecting and I'm not sure why. Any ideas on how to fix this test would be much appreciated.

Comment: it looks like `url` is a reference to a function, I think you'll need to call `composeValidators(url(value))` and `composeValidators(required("some value?"))`

Comment: I've tried doing this and sadly both functions are still returning [function]

Comment: Any other ideas from anyone?

Comment: `composeValidators(required, url, ...)("").to.equal("This is required")` or `composeValidators(required, url, ...)("https://stackoverflow.com").to.equal(undefined)` - Never use code you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do love final form. It really helped drill home how to use currying functions. So, the example you grabbed from final form I've personally used with fields.

```
composeValidators(required)(value)
```

Currying is an odd concept that you can get by without needing it so don't fret over not understanding it at first glance.

Let's look at the signature:

`const composeValidators = (...validators) => (value) =>`

The first function takes X number of props or validation rules. You've got that part down. The second function, now, expects a value. You probably saw it used with Field's validate props. If you look at the documentation for FieldProps (see link below), you'll see it takes a function and passes it 3 arguments, value, allValues, and meta, not just value. This can help you write better validation rules that take into account more information about the field. Anyway, when final-form uses this, it takes the form of:

```
composeValidators(required)(value, allValues, meta)
```

I don't expect this to make sense right away but it should help you think about one specific use case of currying has some advanced options. Enjoy Final Form!

https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps